# How to Get the value of the checked radio button in a group using type attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add focus to a text area using jQuery.

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
  $("#mycbxs input[type ='checkbox']").val("");   
  var radioButtonsChecked = $("input[value='']:checked");
  radioButtonsChecked = $("#mycbxs:checked");
  if(radioButtonsChecked == "B") {
    $("#BAcbx").focus();
  }
 
  if(radioButtonsChecked == "M") {
    $("#MAcbx").focus();
  }
 
  if(radioButtonsChecked == "P") {
    $("#PHDcbx").focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mycbxs">
  <br><strong>&nbsp;</strong>
  <br><input type="checkbox" id="BAcbx" value="B"> BA
  <br><input type="checkbox" id="MAcbx" value="M"> MA
  <br><input type="checkbox" id="PHDcbx" value="P"> PHD
</div>

<div id="myinputs">
  <br><strong>Discipline</strong>
  <br><input type="text" id="BAText" size="30">
  <br><input type="text" id="MAText" size="30">
  <br><input type="text" id="PHDText"  size="30">
</div>
```

Any ideas why it is not adding focus on the selected text areas? This is difficult since the HTML does not have a "Name" attribute (this is on purpose).

Thank you for help.

Comment: Why do you void checkbox values In second line ?

Comment: Also the 4th line is weird. you are updating  radiobuttonChecked to what?

Comment: @Ali, On the 4th line I am updating radioButtonChecked to the id of the div which contains all of the checkboxes. What I am trying to do is: when i click on one of the radio buttons it will add focus to the correlating text input area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
   var radioButtonsChecked= $(this).val();
   if(radioButtonsChecked == "B") { $("#BAcbx").focus(); } 
   if(radioButtonsChecked == "M") { $("#MAcbx").focus(); } 
   if(radioButtonsChecked == "P") { $("#PHDcbx").focus(); }
  })
```

However in this case i suggest radio button so there is no multiple selection

Comment: good looking code but it still does not add the .focus to the correlating text fields: <div id="myinputs">
    <br><strong>Discipline</strong>
    <br><input type="text" id="BAText" size="30">
    <br><input type="text" id="MAText" size="30">
    <br><input type="text" id="PHDText"  size="30">

Comment: you have revealed a new series of id(s) in above comment:d They are not the same as ids in your code

Comment: Change BAcbx to BAtext and other ids as well

Comment: Genius, thank you Ali, the last comment of changing to BAText worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `radioButtonsChecked.val() == "B"` instead of `radioButtonsChecked == "B"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
 if($(this).is(':checked')){
  $('#' + $(this).attr('text-id')).focus();
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mycbxs">
  <br><strong>&nbsp;</strong>
  <br><input type="checkbox" id="BAcbx" text-id="BAText" value="B"> BA
  <br><input type="checkbox" id="MAcbx" text-id="MAText" value="M"> MA
  <br><input type="checkbox" id="PHDcbx" text-id="PHDText" value="P"> PHD
</div>

<div id="myinputs">
  <br><strong>Discipline</strong>
  <br><input type="text" id="BAText" size="30">
  <br><input type="text" id="MAText" size="30">
  <br><input type="text" id="PHDText"  size="30">
</div>
```

I've used one extra attribute `text-id` in checkbox to keep the `input textbox id`

Hope this will help you.